# Numeric sort fails to properly sort file

Tags: sort, join

I used the sort command to numerically sort file1.txt.

```
~]# sort -n -o file1.txt file1.txt
0 Barack
50 George
60 Ronald
100 Bill
```

The sort check command states the file is not sorted.

```
~]# sort -c file1.txt
sort: file1.txt:4: disorder: 100 Bill
```

I manually modify the file and place "100 Bill" second.

```
~]# cat file1.txt
0 Barack
100 Bill
50 George
60 Ronald
```

Now, the sort check command produces no stdout or stderr, meaning the file is properly sorted. Once properly sorted, I can now join the files. It seems that the first character is being used to know if the file is sorted instead of the entire integer.

```
sort -c file1.txt
```

Is there a way to sort the file so that "100 Bill" is on line 2? I cannot do this manually, as the real application of this issue deals with hundreds of lines of text processed by a daily job.

Comment: The file _is properly sorted_ in both cases. In the 1st case you sort it numerically, in the second case it's sorted lexicographically (via your edit - which is the same as running `sort file1.txt`). What is your actual question ? `sort -c` complains because you're asking it to verify if your file is sorted lexicographically: it isn't as you just sorted it numerically. Try with `sort -c -n file1.txt`.

Comment: I see. I falsely assumed that a numeric sort was required. I just tested with no options (lexicograpically) and the desired results are there. Thanks much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a file with [`join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html), you need to make sure it’s sorted *lexicographically* on the join key, which means you shouldn’t use `-n` with [`sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html). You can always sort the result of the `join` operation again numerically.

When you run `sort -c`, you need to specify the same sorting parameters as you used to sort the file: so if you want to check whether a file is sorted numerically, run `sort -c -n`.

Thus in your case, run `sort -o file1.txt file1.txt` to sort the file lexicographically for use with `join` (using the first field as the join field).

Comment: Thanks Stephen. This makes sense now. I mistakenly thought that numeric sort was required. I've made note of this.